# Check If TEdit's Text Property Is Null On A Frame

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

So here is my situation. I have a Form (MainMenu) and a Frame (TestFrame). TestFrame is displayed on a TPanel located on MainMenu. Using this code:

```
frTestFrame := TfrTestFrame.Create(nil);
frTestFrame.Parent := plMain;
frTestFrame.Align := alClient;
frTestFrame.Visible := true;
```

TestFrame displays fine with no error. TestFrame has a few TEdit boxes on it. A TButton on MainMenu calls a procedure located in TestFrame to check if the TEdit boxes text property is null.

```
procedure TfmMainMenu.tbCheckClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
frTestFrame.Check;
end;
```

This function on TestFrame is supposed to go through all the "TEdit" components and use the function GetErrorData that returns a string if the TEdit's text property is null. That string is added to a TStringList and displayed if any TEdit boxes are null.

```
function TfrTestFrame.Check: Boolean;
var
 ErrorList: TStringList;
 ErrorString: string;
 I: Integer;
begin
 ErrorList := TStringList.Create;
 for I := 0 to (frTestFrame.ComponentCount - 1) do
begin
  if (frTestFrame.Components[I] is TEdit) then
    begin
      ErrorString := GetErrorData(frTestFrame.Components[I]);
      if (ErrorString <> '') then
        begin
          ErrorList.Add(ErrorString);
        end;
    end;
end;
if (ErrorList.Count > 0) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Please Add The Following Information: ' + #13#10 + ErrorList.Text);
  result := false;
end;
result := true;
end;

function TfrTestFrame.GetErrorData(Sender: TObject): string;
var
 Editbox: TEdit;
 ErrorString: string;
begin
if (Sender is TEdit) then
 begin
   Editbox := TEdit(Sender);
   if (Editbox.Text <> '') then
     begin
       Editbox.Color := clWindow;
       result := '';
     end
   else
    begin
      Editbox.Color := clRed;
      ErrorString := Editbox.Hint;
      result := ErrorString;
    end;
end;
end;
```

The problem is that when it hits the line "for I := 0 to (frTestFrame.ComponentCount - 1) do
" It blows up and I get the error "Access violation at 0x00458... Read of address 0x000..."
I do not know why this error is happening. I can only assume that maybe the Frame is not getting creating. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TfrTestFrame.Check()` is leaking the `TStringList`.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I freed it at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your question, the line

```
for I := 0 to (frTestFrame.ComponentCount - 1) do
```

leads to an access violation at address `0x000....`. Now, for a start, why won't you tell us the precise error message with the full details? Hiding the address makes it harder!

Anyway, it looks like the address is going to be a value very close to zero. In any case the only explanation for an access violation there is that `frTestFrame` is invalid. Most likely it is `nil`.

I note that the code in question is inside a `TfrTestFrame` method. So why do you use `frTestFrame` to refer to the object? You are already inside an instance of the object. Do you have multiple global variables named `frTestFrame`? Perhaps one in the main form unit and one in the frame unit?

You should stop using global variables for your GUI objects. I know that the IDE leads you that way. Resist the temptation to program that way. Abuse of global variables leads to pain and suffering.

Since the code is inside a `TfrTestFrame` method you can use `Self`. In all your `TfrTestFrame` methods remove all references to `frTestFrame`. Your loop should be like this:

```
for I := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
```

and the rest of the methods in that class need similar treatment. Note that you don't need to explicitly write `Self` and it is idiomatic not to.

Finally, I urge you to learn how to use the debugger. It's a wonderful tool and if you would use it, it would have told you what the problem was. Don't be helpless, let the tools help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I removed the global variable and I am not receiving the error but the function that was located in hits that line and skips to the end.

Comment: The debugger states that the component count is zero. But there are 5 tedit boxes on the frame.

Comment: Are they owned by some other object, the form perhaps. Rather than walking owned components, use ControlCount and Controls[] to walk the children.

Comment: That makes sense so I gave it a try. It did not pick up the text boxes. I am assuming they are not controls.

Comment: Yes, they are controls.  If they are not appearing in the `TFrame`'s list of controls, then the `TFrame` is not their immediate `Parent`. The `Components` list of owned components does not care about Parent-Child relationships, but the `Controls` list does. Are your `TEdit` controls inside the client area of another control (like a `TPanel`) within the `TFrame`, instead of inside the client area of the `TFrame` itself?

Comment: The tedit boxes are just on the frame. They are not in a panel or some other control.

Comment: You should not be iterating over the owned components. It's the wrong approach. Iterate over the child controls.

Comment: I noticed that in my code to display the frame that I am assigning the frame to a panel on the form.

Comment: frAddCustomer := TfrAddCustomer.Create(nil);
    frAddCustomer.Parent := plMain;
    frAddCustomer.Align := alClient;
    frAddCustomer.Visible := true;

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want from me. Surely I answered the question that you asked. You asked about the AV. And you have confirmed that my answer explained that. We cannot conduct a debugging session in comments when only one of us can see the code.

Comment: Remy - Maybe I am making this harder than what it needs to be. Your statement is correct. The Frame is displayed on a TPanel which is located on the Main TForm. When the TFrame is displayed I am setting the TFrame.Parent property to the TPanel on the Main TForm. What I need to do is figure out how to iterate through the TEdit boxes on the Frame.

Comment: Iterate through the frame's Controls.